# Show drawer items using createDrawerNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-drawer

I'm creating a Drawer using `createDrawerNavigator` and creating a `customDrawerComponent` when I'm passing `<DrawerItems {...props} />` it's giving me Error:

`Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.Your likely from forget to export your component from the file it's defined in,  or might have mixed up default and named imports.`

I don't understand what is wrong in my code. please help me to fix it.

here is my Code:
    App.js

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
Home_Page: { screen: HomePage }

})

//customdrawerComponent start here

const customDrawerComponent = (props) => {
return (
    <Fragment>
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: "#9dc7c1" }} />
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }}>

            <View>
                <Text
                    style={{
                        marginTop: 10,
                        marginHorizontal: 20,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: "500",
                        color: "#ffffff"
                    }}
                >
                    Parent name
                </Text>
            </View>
            <ScrollView>
                <DrawerItems {...props} />
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    </Fragment>
)
}

//End here

const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Home_Page: { screen: AppStackNavigator },
        Signout: { screen: SignOut }
    },
    {
        drawerPosition: "left",
        contentComponent: customDrawerComponent,
    }
);

const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Decision: { screen: Decision },
    Login_Screen: { screen: Login },
    Otp: { screen: OtpScreen },
    Home: { screen: DrawerNav }
});

const Container = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

HomePage.js

```
export default HomePage class extends Component{
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {

  return{
    title: 'Home',
    headerLeft: null,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#ff6a00"
    },
    headerLeft:(
      <View style={{paddingLeft:10}}>
       <Icon name='toggle-right' size={25}
       color="#ffffff"
       onPress={()=> navigation.openDrawer()}
       />
      </View>
    ),
    headerTitleStyle: {
      flex: 1,
      color: "#fff",
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
      fontWeight: "600"
    }

  }

  };
   render(){
   return(
  <View>
  </View>
   )
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you plz share whole code file, Because there seems to be some outer mistake

Comment: Have you export 'Container' in last line App.js? and where is all import statement?

Comment: yes..`export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      userName:null
    }
    this.getUserName()
  }
  getUserName = async() => {

    const userName = await AsyncStorage.getItem("username")
    this.setState({userName:userName})

  }

componentDidMount(){
    SplashScreen.hide()
  }
    render(){
      return(
       <Container />
      )
    }
}`